# deleting a record leading to loss of records in another table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

There is a many-to-many relationship between 
`products` & `suppliers`
 (joining table is `products_suppliers`).

Since every `supplier` has a `price` of a `product`, and this price may also change, I have the following relationship as well:
`products_suppliers <-> unit_prices (1:N)`.

Now, if I want to break the relationship between a `product` & a `supplier` (e.g. bec. the supplier doesn't supply the product any more), I would delete the one record in the `products_suppliers` table. However, this will destroy the access to the `price` history of the product from that supplier.

How to do this properly?

I have a problem in the deletion part. I don't know how to deal with it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a field to your `products_suppliers` table, which you can use to indicate whether the product-to-supplier relationship is still active. You could call it "active", or reverse the logic and call it "archived" or "inactive".

This will probably force you to change your queries in other parts of the application, but it will allow you to preserve that link to your price history table. It also has the advantage that if a supplier starts to carry a product again, then you just change the flag in the `products_suppliers` table again.